# Is there a way that logstash writes output to particular database and elastic search read the value from same database

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, devops, elastic-stack, elk

My requirement is to load data from filebeat to logstash and write those data to mongoDB and in elastic search i should be able to read from database where i stored my data using logstash.
I am very new to elk.

I am able to store my data to mongoDB but i am not getting steps to read in elastic search.

Comment: elastic is yet another database; do you really need data in both elastic and mongodb? if you need duplicated data, just have a logstash pipeline that outputs to both dbs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Logstash is a tool for sending logs to some destinations.
2. Databases are places to store data
   ElasticSearch and other databases can't take data from from somewhere, they only has functionality to store data.

## **Solution:**

Logstash has functionality to write to multiple destinations, so you can configure logstash to write into your both databases: elastic and mongoDB

### **example**:

config path: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.conf

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["https://${OPENSEARCH_URL}:443"]
      index => "logs-%{[kubernetes][namespace]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

  }
  mongodb {
    collection => "%{foo}"
    database   => "YOUR_DB_NAME"
    uri        => "mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all go through the elastic documentation, you can find most of your answers there.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/index.html.

Secondly, above given solution is correct, basically you have to configure the following file, and run it with command accordingly.

```
logstash.conf  
logstash -f logstash.conf
```

To be clear I'm giving the example as following: go to the https://www.kaggle.com website where you can find datasets for free. Download any sample, then configure your file. In below example flowers1.csv dataset is downloaded, and its path is set accordingly, and you have to use 'filter' to set the index of column, and set the output to elasticsearch localhost database:

```
logstash.conf
input {
   file {
     path => "C:/elastic_stack/logstash-8.6.2/data3/flowers1.csv"
     start_position => "beginning"
     sincedb_path => "NULL"
        }
      }
filter {
  csv {
    separator => ","
    columns => ["Common Name", "Botanical Name", "Family",   
    "Description"]
      }
   }
output {
  elasticsearch { 
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  index => "csv_flowers_data_test"
  document_id => "%{index}"
       }
 stdout { codec => rubydebug }
 }
```

Lastly learn how to use kibana as well https://www.elastic.co/kr/kibana, it helps you to visualise your data.